# RESETEAR BOTÓN AL ENVIAR FORMULARIO [DUPLICADO]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario con 3 inputs y el botón. La idea es que cuando los inputs estén vacíos el botón se deshabilite. Al pararme en el form el botón se deshabilita, y no se habilita hasta que los inputs estén llenos pero cuando doy click el formulario, este guarda la información y se resetea ya que en el evento submit tengo: e.preventDefault.

Lo que no logro es lo siguiente: 
Cuando envió el formulario se resetea, pero el botón no se deshabilita. Y los campos están vacíos. Como lograrían eso? he investigado mucho y no logro la solución. uso este código. 
Me caería bien la ayuda.

EDITO: El problema es el siguiente. cuando se envía el formulario, los inputs y el select se resetean, pero el boton queda activo (enabled), y deberia quedar disabled, ya que no hay nada en ellos debido al reseteo.

**El script funciona cuando me paro sobre el y lleno todos los campos pero al resetear sucede el problema**

HTML:

```
<form id="contentCreate">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="IDENTIFICADOR" maxlength="26">
     <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="IDENTIFICADOR" maxlength="26">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="IDENTIFICADOR" maxlength="26">
     <select>
        <option><option><!--Los traigo de la BD-->
    <select>
    <input type="submit"  id="buttom" name="" value="CREAR" >
</form>
```

JQ:

```
    $('#contentCreate').submit(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
/*Cuando inserten los datos y envien el formulario los inputs y el select se resetean*/
    });

    $("input[type='text'], select").change(function(){
               /*Inicio deshabilitando el botón*/
                let button = $('#buttom').prop('disabled', true);
                /*Los elementos vaciós los guardo en la variable*/
                let buttonDisabled = $('#id').val() =='' || $('#name').val() =='' || $('#surname').val() =='';
                /*Realizo la comprobación */
                if (buttonDisabled !== true){
                    $('#buttom').prop('disabled', false);//HABILITADO
                }else{
                    $('#buttom').prop('disabled', true);//INHABILITADO
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

la propiedad `disabled` no funciona asi.

Si la propiedad esta presente, con el valor que sea (true, false, pepe, paco, 1, etc...) el control quedara en este estado.(disabled)

Para que se vuelva a poder usar este control debes eliminar esta propiedad.

en Jquery seria algo asi:

```
$("#buttom").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

**EDITO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //para mejorar el comportamiento, usa el evento 'keypress' 
  $("#inputNombre").change(function(event) {
    if (compruebaTextos()) {
      boton(true);
    } else {
      boton(false);
    }
  });
  //para mejorar el comportamiento, usa el evento 'keypress' 
  $("#inputApellido").change(function(event) {
    if (compruebaTextos()) {
      boton(true);
    } else {
      boton(false);
    }
  });

  $("#botonSend").click(function(event) {
    alert("clicki");
  });
});

function compruebaTextos() {
  var resultado = false;
  if ($("#inputNombre").val().trim().length > 0 && $("#inputApellido").val().trim().length > 0) {
    resultado = true;
  }
  return resultado;
}

function boton(accion) {
  if (accion) {
    $("#botonSend").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#botonSend").attr('disabled', 'true');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>pruebas</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="inputNombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input id="inputApellido" type="text" placeholder="Apellido">
  <button id="botonSend" disabled="true">Send</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDITO POR TU MODIFICACIÓN**

Voy a explicar un poco el código que has puesto, y comentare lo que veo raro o lo que se debería hacer para que funcione lo que quieres.

Hablemos de este código:

```
$('#contentCreate').submit(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
/*Cuando inserten los datos y envíen el formulario los inputs y el select se resetean*/
    });
```

Esto lo que hace es evitar que los eventos se propaguen por toda la pagina, en este caso evitamos que si tienes mas formularios, se disparen también el evento en estos.

Ahora hablemos de este código:

```
$("input[type='text'], select").change(function(){
    /*Inicio deshabilitando el botón*/
    let button = $('#buttom').prop('disabled', true);
    /*Los elementos vaciós los guardo en la variable*/
    let buttonDisabled = $('#id').val() =='' || $('#name').val() =='' || $('#surname').val() =='';
    /*Realizo la comprobación */
    if (buttonDisabled !== true){
        $('#buttom').prop('disabled', false);//HABILITADO
    }else{
        $('#buttom').prop('disabled', true);//INHABILITADO
    }
});
```

Utilizas `.change()`, lo que quiere decir que todos este bloque se disparara cuando `input[type='text']` o `select` cambien.

Después haces:

`let button = $('#buttom').prop('disabled', true);`

Esto no es normal, no digo que este mal, no es normal, lo normal es agregar un objeto a una variable. Por ejemplo:

```
let button = $('#buttom');
```

y después ya haces lo siguiente:

```
button.prop('disabled', true);
```

Después tenemos esta variable, que no termino de entender:

```
let buttonDisabled = $('#id').val() =='' || $('#name').val() =='' || $('#surname').val() =='';
```

No existe ninguna `id` que nombras, al  menos en el código que pasaste, por lo tanto esto es `undefined`, ni `false` ni `true`

Y por ultimo el `if`

```
if (buttonDisabled !== true){
     $('#buttom').prop('disabled', false);//HABILITADO
 }else{
     $('#buttom').prop('disabled', true);//INHABILITADO
 }
```

Como hemos dicho `buttonDisabled` valdrá siempre `undefined`, por lo tanto no es `true` (`buttonDisabled !== true`), por lo tanto siempre ejecutara:

```
$('#buttom').prop('disabled', false);//HABILITADO
```

Cambiando el `if` debería de ir todo como esperas.

Espero que esto te sirva de aclaración.

Comment: Bro gracias por la respuesta. Había intentado de esa forma anteriormente pero obtengo el mismo resultado. Retira el disabled cuando los inputs están llenos, pero cuando envío el formulario el botón queda habilitado y se desabilita unicamente si doy click sobre otro 'boton' o refresco la pagina :/

Comment: depende de la version de JQuery no funciona muy fino el removerAttr, prueba con removeProp()

Comment: No anda broda, no entiendo como hacerlo funcionar :/ podría editar el post y colocar todo el código que uso para darme a entender mejor.

Comment: ok, dame un minuto

Comment: recuerda que si te sirvio la solucion, marcala como tal, asi los demas sabran como lo solucionaste.

Comment: Broda no es el problema que busco resolver :( Incluí tu código html en un form y reseteo el form cuando doy click y el botón queda activo.($('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });) Agradezco mucho tus respuestas eres muy amable.

Comment: No te termino de entender, su puedes modifica la pregunta, y pon el codigo nuevo, asi sabremos como esta el codigo. gracias!

Comment: Vale, lo hago enseguida